# Django 1.9 Tutorial Part 2: No module named 'polls.apps' when running python manage.py makemigrations polls

Tags: python, django

There are numerous similar questions here on SO, but they all seem to be for older versions, or are related to a typo.

In [part 2 of the Django 1.9 tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial02/), I am stuck at the initial migration for the polls app:

`python manage.py makemigrations polls`

When running this, I get the error: `ImportError: No module named 'polls.apps'

I am using `Python 3.5.1` and `Django 1.9.4`

excerpt from `mysite/settings.py`

```
...
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
...
```

Folder structure:

```
.
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── mysite
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── polls
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __pycache__
    ├── admin.py
    ├── models.py
    ├── tests.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── views.py

4 directories, 21 files
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing the `apps.py` file (and the `polls.migrations` package also) which should have been generated on this step: [Creating the Polls app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/#creating-the-polls-app). Please review to ensure you've completed that step correctly.

Comment: You are correct, I'm not sure why that file wasn't there, but wiping the `polls` folder and rerunning `python manage.py startapp polls` corrected the issue. **EDIT** All mentions were correct - what happened was, I had run the command in another terminal tab which wasn't in the correct virtualenv (on Python 2 and likely an older version of Django), surprisingly it ran without error anyhow.

Comment: Perhaps you were using a different version of Django when you ran `startapp` before. Django 1.8 and earlier do not create `apps.py` when you run `python manage.py startapp`.

Comment: @Alasdair but, in this case, I suspect there should have been the `migrations` package created, right? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, Django 1.8 should create the migrations package, so my theory might be wrong.

Comment: @Alasdair I think you are still correct, it was probably django 1.6 or earlier that was used to create the app. Interesting case though, since the OP says no errors were raised on the way.

Comment: Yes it's strange, as mentioned, I accidentally ran `startapp` in another window outside of the virtualenv, which, having just now checked is running `django 1.6.2` on `python 2.7.9`

Answer (score 5):

What about if you replace

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    ...
]
```

by just

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls',
    ...
]
```

Comment: awesome! I was with the same issue as reported by waffi, but out of the tutorial

Answer (score 0):

yes!
 the settings.py file should contain...

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'polls',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)
```

The tutorial is so frustrating to follow with errors and inexplicable statements:
With Windows, you can't use TimeZone so just use the system timezone. Er,...how??
You just have to set it to None, i.e.:

```
TIME_ZONE = None  # for Windows!!  Was: 'UTC' for Chicago

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = False  ## just use Windows system time
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: tbh, it's an abstruse, 'rabid' app devt tool, not rapid. 
Maybe once you've got the hang of django, but to learn all this weird crap and have to repeat it each time you develop an app or project is for those who are interested in the development tool, the process, rather than just getting on with your project. 
I'm trying http://www.web2py.com/init/default/download  instead.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify which python do you use: python2 or python3.

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.6
$ python3 --version
Python 3.4.3
```

After switching the alias to python3 and re-running the tutorial, I got the missing file `polls/apps.py` (which contains the class `PollsConfig`).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post. Also check this [what can I do instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).